# Python Snakefood module import generalized failure

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, pythonpath

I want to run [snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/doc/snakefood-doc.html) (an AST-based dependency graph analyser; source code can be found [here](https://bitbucket.org/blais/snakefood/src/e0a74fa6260dcd44716d40b4eb404ca024323eac/lib/python/snakefood/gendeps.py?at=default)). My project has a structureinvolving several levels of Python packages, like this:

```
myproject
 |code
  |Utils
   |AdaptedConfigParser
    Configs_Parser.py
    ...
 ...
 main.py
```

However, when I start running snakefood on the root directory of my project it claims that it can't find the modules from my Python package being imported:

```
$ sfood --internal --follow --ignore-unused ./PycharmProjects/myproject/ > ~/static_analysis.txt
WARNING     :     Line 9: Could not import module 'myproject.Utils.AdaptedConfigParser.Configs_parser'
```

I tried to get around it by adding a `.pth` file with the project root to the `lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Now when I call python with that virtual environment activated from anywhere, I can do the following:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.6rc1 (default, Jan 19 2014, 18:57:40) 
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-4)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import myproject.Utils.AdaptedConfigParser.Configs_parser
>>>
```

And it works just fine.

However, when snakefood is launched with that virtual environement, it still returns the same error.

```
$ sfood --internal --follow --ignore-unused ./PycharmProjects/myproject/ > ~/static_analysis.txt
WARNING     :     Line 9: Could not import module 'myproject.Utils.AdaptedConfigParser.Configs_parser'
```

At this point I don't even understand where the problem with imports could come from.

In addition to that, when `--internal` flag is taken away, it fails imports even of the python `builtin` module, which doesn't make any sense to me:

```
WARNING     :     Line 80: Could not import module 'builtins'
WARNING     :     Line 190: Could not import module 'pyamg'
```

Have anyone encountered such a problem previously? If yes, is there a way of getting around it?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issues, turns out the warning in my case was generated because of `__all__` declarations.

e.g.

```
__all__ = ['abc',
           'aaa',
           ...
          ]
```

Above code gives out the warnings:

```
WARNING     :     Line xx: Could not import module 'abc'
WARNING     :     Line xx: Could not import module 'aaa'
```

I modified the warning constant `ERROR_IMPORT` within `snakefood\lib\python\find.py` to add the name of the file where the error occurs along with the line number and module name. That way you can target the specific file and line number pretty much figure out the problem.

Hope this helps!